# getting "invalid column" when trying to use column alias in a query

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to use a column alias i created in a query, inside a formula in the same query for a different column. what am i doing wrong here and how can i fix it? here the code to explain myself better:

```
SELECT TestTabI.Month, TestTabI.Year, AccessEntityList.Region, 
AccessEntityList.[Audit Tier], AccessEntityList.[Parent Group],
case 
when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='U.S.' 
then [NF PTI] 
else 0 
end AS [US Pretax Income], 

case 
when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='Non-U.S.' 
then [NF PTI] 
else 0 
end AS [FN Pretax Income],

[US Pretax Income]+[FN Pretax Income] AS [Total Pretax Income] FROM AccessEntityList
INNER JOIN TestTabI ON AccessEntityList.[Entity Number] = 
TestTabI.[Entity Number] WHERE (((TestTabI.Month)=12) AND ((TestTabI.Year)=2010)
```

" [US Pretax Income]+[FN Pretax Income] AS [Total Pretax Income] " gives me the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'US Pretax Income'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'FN Pretax Income'.
```

Comment: that is one UGLY query, the formatting and names couldn't get any worse!  FYI, all of these work: `select 1 as one; select 1 as "one !"; select 1 as [one !]; select 1 as 'one !';`  I'd check your column name spellings and that they are in the tables you think they are.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your case statements in a `cross apply` can use the aliases.

```
select TestTabI.Month,
       TestTabI.Year,
       AccessEntityList.Region, 
       AccessEntityList.[Audit Tier], 
       AccessEntityList.[Parent Group],
       C.[US Pretax Income], 
       C.[FN Pretax Income],
       C.[US Pretax Income]+C.[FN Pretax Income] AS [Total Pretax Income] 
from AccessEntityList
  inner join TestTabI 
    on AccessEntityList.[Entity Number] = TestTabI.[Entity Number] 
  cross apply
    (
     select case 
              when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='U.S.' 
              then [NF PTI] 
              else 0 
            end as [US Pretax Income], 
            case 
              when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='Non-U.S.' 
              then [NF PTI] 
              else 0 
            end as [FN Pretax Income]
    ) as C
where TestTabI.Month=12 and TestTabI.Year=2010
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the alias you just defined on a `SELECT` on that same `SELECT`. Either use a CTE or a derived table for this:

```
SELECT A.*, [US Pretax Income]+[FN Pretax Income] AS [Total Pretax Income] 
FROM (
SELECT  TestTabI.Month, TestTabI.Year, AccessEntityList.Region, 
        AccessEntityList.[Audit Tier], AccessEntityList.[Parent Group],
        case when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='U.S.' then [NF PTI] 
        else 0 end AS [US Pretax Income], 
        case when AccessEntityList.[Jurisdiction]='Non-U.S.' 
        then [NF PTI] else 0 end AS [FN Pretax Income]
FROM AccessEntityList
INNER JOIN TestTabI 
ON AccessEntityList.[Entity Number] = TestTabI.[Entity Number]
WHERE (((TestTabI.Month)=12) AND ((TestTabI.Year)=2010)) A
```

Comment: Or if you want to do it the convoluted way, you can copy your two case statements into the summed alias :) - but I'd use the method Lamak said

Answer (score 0):

I typically use no spaces in my column names, so am unfamiliar with this bracket syntax. Are you sure it works for alias declaration?

For your aliases try replacing brackets with backticks so:

```
end AS `US Pretax Income`,
```

Comment: in SQL Server (what the question is tagged), you will get **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '`'.** if you try to use a back-tick as you recommend.